# Flask app with ArcGIS, Arcpy does not run

Tags: python, flask, arcpy, pymssql

I have a script that gets a table from MSSQL database and then registers it with ArcGIS. It uses several other arcpy methods as well. I tried to combine it with Flask and developed an HTML interface where you can specify tables. The script runs on console perfectly well, however, when running with Flask on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ , the arcpy functions do not run, then the app throws errors.

I am using my local python directory, so I do not have any problem with importing arcpy on flask. So, I am able to use pymssql functions and create a new table, however when it comes to arcpy function, It throws does not exist error, however, the table exists. I feel like there is something wrong with running arcpy with Flask, but any help would be appreciated.

(2) I tried the same thing in Django but I am having the same problem.

Thanks

## forms.py

```
class createGISLayer(FlaskForm):
    tCreateLayer = SubmitField('Create GIS Layer')
```

## DashboardMain()

```
   try:
        cursor.execute(QueryCreate)
        print ("Table Created.")
        print(self.dbTablePath)
        descTable = arcpy.Describe(self.dbTablePath)

    except arcpy.ExecuteError:
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

## app.py

```
if formCreate.tCreateLayer.data and formCreate.validate_on_submit():
    if myLayer is not None:
        try:
            print("Create GIS Layer")
            myLayer.dashboardMain()
            flash('GIS Layer created!', 'success')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)
            flash(e.message, 'danger')
```

## index.html

```
<!-- Create GIS Layer  -->
<div class="content-section">
<form name='idCreateGISLayer' action="" method="POST">
<table style="height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 600px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    {{ formCreate.hidden_tag() }}
    <td style="height: 39px; width: 259px">
        <h2 style="text-align: left;"><font size="3"><strong>(2) Create </strong></font></h2>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left; height: 39px;">
        <div class="auto-style2">                                                                
            {{ formCreate.tCreateLayer(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </form>
 </div>
```

## ERROR

```
Table Created.
F:\Projects\Dashboard\Publish.sde\Publish.dbo.A_WebT1
"F:\Projects\Dashboard\Publish.sde\Publish.dbo.A_WebT1" does not exist
```

## screenshot

[image: Table exists]

Comment: Can you check if python can access the file using pathlib:`from pathlib import Path
dbTablePath = ...
# list all files in the directory  
p = Path(dbTablePath)  
for f in p.iterdir():  
    print(f)  
# or  
for f in p.parent.iterdir():  
    print(f)
`

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, ArcGIS maintains it's own python environment (and used to install it over existing installations, ick). So unless you're using that environment when you launch/run flask, you're likely not getting the config/resources loaded that are needed to support Arcpy functions. It's like trying to load a library installed into a different python virtual environment. You can provide the path, but if it requires any additional content or configuration from it's own venv, it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling the function, I ran my script with DOS.

```
@app.route('/cad2json', methods=['POST'])
def cad2sde():
    dwg_path = request.form.get('dwg_path')
    reference_scale = request.form.get('reference_scale')
    spatial_reference = request.form.get('spatial_reference')
    target_layer = request.form.get('target_layer')
    sentence =   (u'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\python.exe C:\\Users\\Administrator           \\Desktop\\flask\\cad.py %s %s %s %s'
             %(dwg_path,reference_scale,spatial_reference,target_layer))
    p = os.popen(sentence)
    return format(p.read())
```

Comment: you need to describe how your answer fits to the requirement at hand

Comment: In this case, the .py file should be under the same directory of python.exe. And unfortunately, you can not trace any error either. I have been looking for the solution still. There should be something to do with path.

Answer (score -3):

ArcPy is not free. It only works in ESRI software or anaconda. You can not import.