# arcpy in django doesnot run

Tags: django, arcpy

I have a script with ArcGIS using arcpy model. And I want to combine it with Django. The script runs on console successfully, however, when running with Django, I find the arcpy functions do not run. So I make a simple test for it, and get the same result.

## test.py

```
import arcpy
import os

def test_arcpy():
    tempFolder = arcpy.env.scratchFolder
    tempGDBPath = os.path.join(tempFolder, 'test.gdb')
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    if not arcpy.Exists(tempGDBPath):
        arcpy.AddMessage('create..')
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(tempFolder, 'test.gdb')
    return arcpy.Exists(tempGDBPath)
```

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import test
def t(request):
    msg = str(test.test_arcpy())
    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

If I run the test.py in console, it return True.But if I run it in django, it always return false. If I cannot solve it , I cannot make more difficult script in django. Can you help me?
I found the similar question in [Flask app with ArcGIS, Arcpy does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292905/flask-app-with-arcgis-arcpy-does-not-run), but no solution in this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use the subprocess model to run the arcpy script in console, and then return the console message back to the django function.
But I really want to know whether arcpy can run with django or not.

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same problem the same as you in Flask.

I check the source code in `arcpy`, found there is an bug in `arcgisscripting.pyd` file while i trigger `arcpy.Exists()` from Flask. And i lost any clew. After searching for some case on ESRI online blog, i certainly found that it's a bug in arcpy. So i advice u:

1. try higher version arcpy.(my current version is 10.1)
2. try to run your code in a console
3. try to run message queue like `from multiprocessing import Queue, Process`
4. try to not use the function. In my case, I avoid to use `arcpy.Exists()`
5. try to use 64-bit arcpy in arcServer.